# LinkedHashMap in Perl

Tags: java, perl, linkedhashmap, lru

Is there some data structure in Perl like LinkedHashMap  in java?

Or something LRU data structure in Perl

Update:@TLP Basically  I'd like to have Hashtable data structure but also I can keep the order of keys coming in, remove keys after I process the key in the list.

Update:@ccheneson   Tie::IxHash one seems not what i want, I would like to POP an oldest key, but tie::ixHash pop up the latest key, How I get the oldest key value pair in Tie::IxHash? I'd like to have a queue Structure (and Hash Structure as well, I'd like to find the key in the easiest way), new Key,value pair keeps coming in and I keep process oldest Key and remove the oldest key.

Update:@ FMc Tie::IxHash is What I need, Tie::IxHash->Shift() does a queue pop Tie::IxHash->Push() does queue push  and it is hash structure and easy to find keys.

Thanks all.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what functionality you are after, for those who are fluent in perl, but not in java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/~chorny/Tie-IxHash-1.22/lib/Tie/IxHash.pm) seems to be what you are looking for.

> Tie::IxHash - ordered associative arrays for Perl

Comment: this one seems not what i want, I would like to POP an oldest key, but tie::ixHash pop up the latest key, How I get the oldest key value pair in Tie::IxHash?

Comment: @icn See the example in the module's documentation: `($k, $v) = $t->Shift`.